# Submenu in sidebar custom page template

Tags: menus, sidebar

i would like to show the submenu of my page in a custom page template on the left side in a Sidebar-area. Does any know the code for showing the submenu. Wordpress 3.4.1

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to code this yourself, all the info you need is in the Wordpress Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages

Alternatively you could use a widget like the [BE Subpages Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/be-subpages-widget/)

Comment: thanks a lot. but nothing happens. either self made or with the plugin. Under Appearance - Menues i drag'nDropped the submenu items a bit besides the top menu item to the right. do i have to edit sth in the functions.php so he recognizes it as a submenu?

Comment: got it. did not set the page as a subpage in the "Pages" page. thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it. Things like that can be tough to debug!

Comment: I just want to point out that the answer is listing sub-pages, not sub menu items